# Dificulties in using BASH variable and conditional IF combined

Tags: bash, scripting

Someone could help me?

```
for k in {1..10001}
do
if [ -d "$k" ]
    then
        cd $k/
        testfile="grep Have aims.out | cut -c11-14"
        cd ..
fi
if [[ "$testfile" == "Have" ]]  
    then
        mv $k $k_OK
fi
done
```

The part in which should change the directories name does't work. I think that I'm using the variable testfile incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Value of your `$testfile` is `grep Have aims.out | cut -c11-14` which is definitely NOT equals to `Have`. That's why you are not entering second `if`-block at all.
If you want to execute `grep` statement and assign its result to variable, you need to replace quotes with backticks:

```
testfile=`grep Have aims.out | cut -c11-14`
```